# warning when I run npm run build with docker and node16

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, build

I have a react app and I did not eject it. When I build it regularly with `npm run build` I don't get any warning messages. When I do `node -v` in the terminal I get `v16.1.0`.

But when I build it with docker `FROM node:16.1.0-alpine3.12 AS build`

I get the following warning during the build process:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'setup@0.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '15.11.0', npm: '6.4.1' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.11.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

The app works fine, no issues. I did a `npm update` but didn't change anything.

How do I resolve the warning messages?

Comment: This is metadata in the package.json for `setup@0.1.0`.  I don't know what that is, so either that could be broadened to include more recent versions or you can ignore the warning if all seems to be working.

Comment: ohh okk, I don't have this specific package in my package.json, so seems like I can't really do anything ?